# SQL Server trigger to update counter in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to solve this question and I'm having serious issues to get a working solution.

I have 2 tables, `Employees` and `Departments`. Each department has a counter of the number of the employees registered in them.

So, when I insert or delete an `Employee`, with the pertinent department name, I need to update the counter of that department in the `Departments` table.

Comment: You would really need to justify why a count is necessary when calculating the count should be pretty fast, even on a reasonably sized database.

Comment: Please google and learn about the CREATE TRIGGER command in SQL.

Comment: Unless this is some kind of a homework assignment, and infact, even if it is, this smells like a bad database design. As Gordor wrote, count is very fast to execute, even with a very large number of records (we are talikng about hundreds of millions here).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a (delete) trigger on Employee table where in after deleting an employee, this trigger runs and update the department table.

CREATE TRIGGER UPDEPT

ON Employee

AFTER DELETE

AS
   UPDATE DEPARTMENT D
   SET D.Empcount = (SELECT COUNT(Employee) WHERE DEPTID = D.DEPTID)
GO

You may have to set the update query as per data in the table.

Comment: But what happens when I INSERT one employee? Should i make another trigger for insert?

Comment: Nope. You can modify the same trigger for Insert or Delete. It will update the department count on each Insert or Delete.